# Impulse given to a rotating rod at the centre VS the end

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, conservation-laws

This is a doubt from a question I have solved, I will extract only my queries from it.

Case1: let a rod of mass '$m$' lie on a smooth table and impulse $Ft$ is given at one of the ends.

(assume the center of mass moves in a straight line )

*in this case the center of mass will move with a velocity $Ft/m$.

$Ft$=change in velocity

$$Ft=mv$$

or $$\frac{Ft}{m}=v$$

*it will also have an angular speed $6Ft/ml$.

applying torque equation,

$$\frac{FtL}{2}=I\omega$$

or $$\frac{Ftl}{2}= \frac{\omega ML^2}{12}$$

or $$\omega=\frac{6Ft}{ml}$$

Case2: Instead of a rod let there be a ball of the same mass '$m$' and an impulse Ft is given

*in this case the ball will only have linear velocity equal to $Ft/m$.

same math as before

**Question:**

Both case 1 and case 2 have the same linear velocity but case 1 has also angular velocity. Is such a situation possible? Is it violating energy conservation?

How can this be? I'm very perplexed and I believe in the legitimacy of the question.

Comment: What about the balls spin about its centre of mass? Wouldn't that take up some energy? Why have you neglected it?

Comment: Can we ignore that effect?@KenzoTenma

Comment: There are are many problems that i see in your method, but i thought to mention only some. For example: you haven't made an explicit calculation on the work done while applying such impulsive force. This weakens your argument as anyone can come up and ask you that why you think the work done in both cases is equal? And your question won't be able to defend itself (unless you do an edit).

Comment: Why do you think similar impulses must carry similar energy?

Comment: Will my current edit suffice?@KenzoTenma

Comment: @BioPhysicist Because I have taken them to be of similar masses.

Comment: @AlexH indeed, How should I have framed it instead?

Comment: Not sure, I haven't read the question in detail. Most likely there's a loophole somewhere. Fundamental laws are good at finding those.

Comment: @JustJohan That doesn't mean equal impulses means equal work. You are dealing with an extended body.

Comment: @BioPhysicist I was not aware, could you elaborate or provide a useful link?

Comment: @JustJohan have a look at this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/516754/249968

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an external impulse, you don't have an isolated system, and you shouldn't be chuffed if you discover that energy has been exchanged with the surroundings via the momentum-changing interaction.

Your particular example — a rod which receives the same impulse at the middle or at the end — is a famous example of an inelastic-collision experiment which confuses people; see for example [this brief Veritasium video](https://youtu.be/vWVZ6APXM4w) and links therein.